# Error producing PDF. Undefined control sequence

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I've been trying to convert my notes from school to a PDF but I keep getting following error:

```
Error producing pdf.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.55 ...i letters:"; cat dutch | grep -vP '(.).*\1
```

I figure this probably has something to do with the usage of a special character that has to be escaped or something like that, but after a bit of googling I still haven't found the solution.

I have tried `pandoc notes.md -o notes.pdf` and `pandoc notes.md -o notes.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex` as commands. Below you can find my notes:

```
# Vraag 1
for i in {14,15,16}; do echo "$i letters:"; cat dutch | grep -vP '(.).*\1' | grep -P "^.{$i}$" ; done

OF

for i in {14,15,16}; do echo "$i letters:" $(cat dutch | grep -vP '(.).*\1' | grep -P "^.{$i}$") ; done

UNIEKE LETTERS: grep -vP '(.).*\1'


# Vraag 2
tshark -r bruteforce.pcap -Y 'ftp.request.command == USER' -T fields -e 'ftp.request.arg' | sort -u


# Vraag 3
echo "Time = $(date '+%X (%x)')"

# Vraag 4
openssl enc -d -a -in secret

OF

cat secret | base64 -d 

# Vraag 4
echo | openssl s_client -connect wiki.uclllabs.be:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -pubkey -serial -fingerprint
```

As you can see the error occurs on the first line, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably those commands should be treated as code blocks? In that case they should be indented:

```
# Vraag 1

    for i in {14,15,16}; do echo "$i letters:"; cat dutch | grep -vP '(.).*\1' | grep -P "^.{$i}$" ; done
```

or fenced:

````
# Vraag 1

```
for i in {14,15,16}; do echo "$i letters:"; cat dutch | grep -vP '(.).*\1' | grep -P "^.{$i}$" ; done
```
````

Both of these variations should compile with Pandoc. I have also added blank lines after your heading. This may not be necessary, but improves readability of the source.

It's probably also an even better idea to break your source blocks up for readability:

````
# Vraag 1

```
for i in {14,15,16}; do
  echo "$i letters:";
  cat dutch | grep -vP '(.).*\1' | grep -P "^.{$i}$";
done
```
````